# Merge nested dictionaries by nested values

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

How can I merge in Python the following nested dictionary using **client_id** values?

```
{
0: {'id': u'171350479985198', 'title': u'Mrs'},
1: {'id': u'171350479985198', 'title': u'Mrs'},
2: {'id': u'81675316423225', 'title': u'NOT EXISTS'},
3: {'id': u'164299819070601', 'title': u'None'},
4: {'id': u'164299819070601', 'title': u'Mrs'},
5: {'family_name': u'FN7988', 'id': u'171350479985198'}, 
6: {'family_name': u'FN1909', 'id': u'171350479985198'}, 
7: {'family_name': u'NOT EXISTS', 'id': u'81675316423225'}, 
8: {'family_name': u'FN759E', 'id': u'164299819070601'}, 
9: {'family_name': u'FN37FD', 'id': u'164299819070601'}, 
10: {'id': u'171350479985198', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'}, 
11: {'id': u'81675316423225', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'}, 
12: {'id': u'164299819070601', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'}
}
```

As a result, I need the following dictionary.

```
{
0: {'id': u'171350479985198', 'title': u'Mrs', 'family_name': u'FN7988', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'}, 
1: {'id': u'171350479985198', 'title': u'Mrs', 'family_name': u'FN1909', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'},
2: {'id': u'81675316423225', 'title': u'NOT EXISTS', 'family_name': u'NOT EXISTS', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'}, 
3: {'id': u'164299819070601', 'title': u'None', 'family_name': u'FN759E', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder' }, 
4: {'id': u'164299819070601', 'title': u'Mrs', 'family_name': u'FN37FD', 'description': u'Recurrent depressive disorder'} 
}
```

Comment: why are there 2 entries for `171350479985198` and `164299819070601`

Comment: You have duplicate data. Which one do you want to take precedence?

Comment: Why there is no dict for `title: None` and `family_name: 'FN37FD'`, for id: `164299819070601`? First it looked like, you've a dict entry for each distinct `title`, `family_name` and `description` combination. But it fails for this id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just going to assume the duplicate records in the result are a mistake and propose the following solution.

```
result = dict()

for key in d:
    if 'id' in d[key]:
        current_id = d[key]['id']
        if current_id not in result:
            result[current_id] = dict() #init dict
        else:
            for sub_key in d[key]:
                if sub_key != 'id':
                    result[current_id][sub_key] =d[key][sub_key]

#Lastly Map back into the numbers

num_result = {}
result_key = [k for k in result]
# You can sort result key by some criteria if you want 

for key_num in xrange(0,len(result_keys)):
    result[result_key[key_num]]['id'] = result_key[key_num] #Adds the id back
    num_result[key_num] = result[result_key[key_num]]

print num_result
```